# Fixing overflow issues when the width of the column is unknown

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on displaying data from a database on a web page.

My problem is that some of the data is very long and does not contain spaces (think very long path names), so it overflows the table without wrapping.

Currently the widths of the columns are determined using `table-layout:auto`, because I am working with a lot of different databases and tables, so I do not want to hard code the widths.

Therefore, when I try and use `overflow:wrap`, it just breaks the other columns into one-letter-wide messes.

**Here are some of my ideas (none of which I can get to work):**

1. Use `table-layout:auto` to calculate the suggested widths, set the widths to be those values, and then set `overflow:wrap`.
2. Tell the browser to break at characters other than just spaces, i.e. '/'.
3. Only set `overflow:wrap` if a column is longer than a certain amount.

I am currently using CSS and a little bit of JavaScript.

**Any other ideas?**

Comment: maybe`min- max`- would be convenient for this

Comment: [word-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) to the rescue

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

`max-width` and `overflow-x` properties in your css

```css
.table tr td {
   max-width: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
       <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
         <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
    </tr>

<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some simple solutions that come to mind:

#### Use ellipses with manually triggered expansion for lines > N chars

```
/a/really/long/file/name/that/is/really/just/too/l... [expand]
```

This can work when the data you're showing doesn't really need to be visible all the time, and the user can choose to view all of it if they are interested. With this one, you don't need to worry about what type of information each cell has.

#### Data-specific column widths

If you know the type of data that will appear in your columns, you can define a mapping to resize the widths of the columns.

This requires some extra work to get the column types and configure the mappings, and then resizing the columns.

```
{ dataTypeWidths: { default: 'auto', filename: '300px' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `max-width` combined with `overflow-x: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsi`, i think that will resolve your problem.

```css
td {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit.Integertellusmassa,fringillaacquamnec,temporconguelectus.Sedimperdietaclacusidtempus.Sedutfelisaduiiaculistemporinasapien.Integervelliberomi.Morbiutenimsagittis,sollicitudinipsumin,ullamcorpersapien.Phasellusidfelisatligulatristiquehendrerit.Nuncsitametipsumidquamtinciduntfacilisis.Pellentesquehabitantmorbitristiquesenectusetnetusetmalesuadafamesacturpisegestas.Namsitametdictumeros.</td>
    <td>Pellentesquefermentummattisleo,sedblandittortorhendreritnec.Vestibulumeuturpislacus.Fusceliberorisus,dignissimegetsodalesnon,dictuminsem.Quisqueblanditmiante,eutristiqueorciporttitorsitamet.Donecpretium,eratetaccumsanfringilla,velitjustotristiqueorci,sedfringillaquamrisusnonenim.Praesenthendreritmassaultriceseratmalesuadapretium.Aeneansitametnuncsodales,vehiculaeroseget,ornarelorem.Proinquisfermentumsapien,utvehiculafelis.Duisquiseleifendleo.Suspendisseinnequefringilla,tristiquelectuseu,fermentumdiam.Nuncmassalectus,aliquamidmassaeu,pretiumullamcorperlectus.Aliquamfeugiatexegetornaretincidunt.Donectristiqueeratseddiamvehiculaauctor.Proinorcijusto,consecteturegetcursusut,pellentesquevelleo.Nampulvinarrisusetnislfacilisisaliquam.</td>
    <td>Inhachabitasseplateadictumst.Craspulvinarsuscipitfelis,ullamcorperpulvinarlorem.Vivamuspulvinarinterdumlibero.Maurisvenenatisaugueodio,aultriceserossuscipitvel.Donecutfelissitameteratconsecteturbibendumegetetnulla.VestibulumanteipsumprimisinfaucibusorciluctusetultricesposuerecubiliaCurae;Crastempus,magnavelelementumlobortis,ipsummassaporttitorarcu,mollisvehiculaanteenimvitaelectus.Fuscemolliseumagnaapretium.Praesentegestasaugueanuncultricies,ataliquamodiodignissim.Insagittismaurisest,sedlacinialeoornareeu.VestibulumanteipsumprimisinfaucibusorciluctusetultricesposuerecubiliaCurae;Namrisusaugue,gravidasedullamcorperin,feugiatetdolor.Maurisposuerenuncquam,necdignissimmassagravidatincidunt.Quisquesemperdiamlibero,intemporlectusullamcorperut.</td>
    <td>Suspendissevenenatisaliquamsapientinciduntconsequat.Aliquamveldiamegetsapienvehiculadapibus.Namblanditamagnaquisiaculis.Orcivariusnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdisparturientmontes,nasceturridiculusmus.Orcivariusnatoquepenatibusetmagnisdisparturientmontes,nasceturridiculusmus.Quisquelacinianunclorem,ultriciesvolutpatduifinibusquis.Praesentmalesuada,odioeuconsequatgravida,nisllacussagittismagna,sitametultriciesquamtellusporttitorelit.Fusceduilorem,viverraquisipsumet,pulvinaraliquamaugue.Donecinterdumscelerisquequamidfaucibus.Sedmollistinciduntquam,ideleifenddiammaximusa.Sedvitaemagnanonlectushendreritlacinia.Donecvenenatisauguevitaepulvinarpulvinar.Etiamposuereapurusetplacerat.Pellentesquefinibusdictumimperdiet.Crascursusfelisvelpellentesquerutrum.</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the width of the column as that will vary by table and database

Comment: Well, could you give an example of how is the page now and how you want it to be?

Comment: Currently one of the tables has five columns, and each of the first four columns has under 15 characters and behaves nicely. The last column ranges from 10 to several hundred characters in length, and the longer entries are not wrapping, which is what I would like to fix. Another table has 10 columns, of varying lengths, with the super long one eighth, causing the last two columns not to show up at all. I am looking for one solution that would fix both of these tables at the same time

Comment: Ok, understood, but you will have to set a maximum width, it will not be the width for all the cells, but the point at witch the content will be wrapped. If you want, it could be set accordingly to the number of cells on that row, but it will need some jquery. I will edit the answer trying to give examples for what im talking about.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

this will keep the columns widths and will show all the data

```css
.table tr td {
   max-width: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
       <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
        <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
         <td>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipiscingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Utenimadminimveniam,quisnostrudexercitationullamcolaborisnisiutaliquipexeacommodoconsequat.</td>
    </tr>

<table>
```

Code snippet copied from @MrMins answer and updated.